# Proving induced matrix norms are still equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I know that if two vector norm's are equivalent it means that there are two constants c,d such that $c\lVert x\rVert_a \leq \lVert x\rVert_b \leq d\lVert x\rVert_a$. How would I go about proving their induced matrix norms are also equivalent so that there exists two different constants $e$,$f$ such that $e\lVert A\rVert_a \leq \lVert A\rVert_b \leq f\lVert A\rVert_a$. I also know I can take advantage of the fact that $\lVert Ax\rVert \leq \lVert A\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert$ for induced matrix norms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x\neq0$, then$$c\|Ax\|_a\leqslant\|Ax\|_b\leqslant\|A\|_b\|x\|_b\leqslant d\|A\|_b\|x\|_a$$and therefore$$\frac{\|Ax\|_a}{\|x\|_a}\leqslant\frac dc\|A\|_b.$$Since this takes place for each $x\neq0$, $\|A\|_a\leqslant\frac dc\|A\|_b$. So, take $e=\frac dc$. In a similar way, you can determine $f$.

Comment: do you mean in a similar way I can determine f? So to go about showing that $\lVert A\rVert_b \leq f\lVert A\rVert_a$ what step should I take?

Comment: @user1775500 Yes, I meant $f$; I've edited my answer. Concerning your question: you know that $\frac1d\|x\|_b\leqslant\|x\|_a\leqslant\frac1c\|x\|_b$. So, by the same arument that I used,$$\|A\|_b\leqslant\frac{1/c}{1/d}\|A\|_a=\frac dc\|A\|_a.$$